# What parts are worth salvaging from a HP dv6402ca laptop?

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion

My HP Pavilion dv6402ca is dead (probably the motherboard), and I was wondering if there are any parts in it worth salvaging aside from the RAM and HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends if you get a replacement laptop the same model. If not, you could grab the CMOS (BIOS) battery and the fan.

Personally, as I'm a bit of a hoarder I'd keep everything apart from the motherboard if it's dead, because I always have a "just in case" moment.

Comment: Unless you are buying a new model with the same physical dimensions, this just about covers it. The keyboard and screen are going to be pretty difficult to swap into a different model, although the key caps are fairly standard.

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the Heat-Pipe(s). This nice copper things are mostly an eye-catcher.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Pop the keyboard onto eBay. Someone else will have put coffee in theirs and will be glad of yours.